# How can I get the latest version of a link from a webpage in Java?

Tags: java

I am working on a code to get the latest link for a download from a page and store it as a String. Basically, the files on the server are stored in a format like this:

```
http://website.com/file/path/file-*version*/filename-*version*.zip
```

*version* is replaced with the version of the file. I would like to get and save the latest version of the file under the name "filename.zip". I currently have started on something that may be able to do it, but I can't figure out how to keep going or if I started off right in the first place. Here is what I have so far:

```
public static void getDownloadPage() throws IOException{
    URL website = new URL("http://website.com/file/path/downloads.html");
    ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(website.openStream());
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("downloads.txt");
    fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
}
public static String findDownloadLinks(){
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner("downloads.txt");
    while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
        if("http://website.com/file/path/file-*/filename-*.zip".equals(scanner.nextLine().trim())){
            // found
            break;
          }else{
           // not found

          }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you even tried it, just to see what happens?

Comment: @Zhedar I just realized I hadn't posted the full code. I have edited it and added the other part. No, I haven't tested it, because 1. I know it is wrong and 2. I haven't gotten to how to make it run in eclipse yet.